# d3 force layout: transition is not a function

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular13

Mi problema se trata en que obtengo el error:

> d3 transition is not a function

en un gráfico de D3 de tipo forcelayout.

Mi código actualmente es:

```
createGraph(){

    const svg = d3.select('#container');

    const svg_container = document.getElementById('map-container')!;
    this.svg_width = svg_container.offsetWidth;
    this.svg_height = svg_container.offsetHeight;
    const centerX = this.svg_width/2;
    const centerY = this.svg_height/2;

    const simulation = forceSimulation(this.NODES)
      .force('charge', forceManyBody().strength(-20))
      .force('link', forceLink(this.LINKS).id((d:any) => d.id).distance(((link: any) => link.distance) as any))
      .force('center', forceCenter(centerX, centerY));
    
    const dragInteraction: any = drag().on('drag', (event: any, node: any) => {
      node.fx = event.x;
      node.fy = event.y;
      simulation.alpha(1);
      simulation.restart();
    });

    const lines = svg
      .selectAll('line')
      .data(this.LINKS)
      .enter()
      .append('line')
      .attr('stroke', ((link: any) => link.color || 'black') as any)
      //.attr('visibility', (link: any) => link.source.type === 'Main' && link.target.type === 'Main' ? 'visible !important' : link.visibility )
      .attr('class', (link: any) => `line-${ link.source.id }`)
      .attr('source', (link: any) => link.source.id )
      .attr('target', (link: any) => link.target.id )
      .attr('type', 'line')

    const circles = svg
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(this.NODES)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('fill', ((node: any) => node.color || 'gray') as any)
      .attr('r', this.radius - .75 /*((node: any) => node.size) as any*/)
      .attr('class', (node: any) => `node-${ node.id }`)
      .attr('id', (node: any) => `node-${ node.id }`)
      //.attr('visibility', (node: any) => node.visibility ? node.visibility : 'hidden')
      .attr('parents', (node: any) => node.parents ? node.parents : '')
      .call(dragInteraction)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", (node:any) => mouseout(node))
      .on("contextmenu", (node:any) =>  alert(JSON.stringify(node.srcElement.__data__)))
      .on("click", (n:any) => displayChildNodes(n.srcElement.__data__))
    
    const text = svg
      .selectAll('text')
      .data(this.NODES)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('text-anchor', ('middle') as any)
      .attr('alignment-baseline', ('middle') as any)
      .attr('class', (node: any) => `text-${ node.id }`)
      .attr('id', (node: any) => `text-${ node.id }`)
      .attr('visibility', (node: any) => node.visibility ? node.visibility : 'hidden')
      .attr('type', 'text')
      .style('pointer-events', ('none') as any)
      .text( (node: any) => node.id );
    
    simulation.on('tick', () => {
      let width = this.svg_width;
      let height = this.svg_height;
        circles
        .attr("cx", function(d: any) { return d.x = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d: any) { return d.y = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d.y)); });
        
        text
          .attr('x', ((node: any) => node.x) as any)
          .attr('y', ((node: any) => node.y) as any);
   
        lines
          .attr('x1', ((link: any) => link.source.x) as any)
          .attr('y1', ((link: any) => link.source.y) as any)
          .attr('x2', ((link: any) => link.target.x) as any)
          .attr('y2', ((link: any) => link.target.y) as any)
      });

    function mouseover(d: any) {
      console.log(d);
        lines
          .attr("stroke","black")
          .attr("stroke-width",2);
        lines
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", function(o: any) {
              return o.source.id === d.srcElement.__data__.id || o.target.id === d.srcElement.__data__.id ? 1 : .1;
          });
        circles
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .attr('r', (node:any) => {
            if(node.id === d.srcElement.__data__.id) return node.size + 15
            return node.size;
          });
    }

    function mouseout(d: any) { 
      lines
        .attr('stroke', ((line: any) => line.color) as any );
      lines
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 1);
      circles
        .attr('fill', ((node: any) => node.color || 'gray') as any)
        .attr('r', ((node: any) => node.size) as any)
      circles
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
     }
```

Los imports de D3 que utilizo:

```
import { forceSimulation, forceLink, forceManyBody, forceCenter, drag } from 'd3';
import * as d3 from 'd3-selection';
```

Cuando ejecuto el proyecto con `ng serve` SI aparecen los nodos y los links, adjunto imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema está cuando realizo el mouseOver/mouseOut en un nodo que es donde salta el error indicado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además si realizo click (para ejecutar la función de click o para arrastrar un nodo) obtengo un error de webpack:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo la causa del error, ni una posible solución. ¿Alguien se ha topado con este problema?

Añado las dependencias de mi package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/forms": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "13.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^16.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/d3": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "ajv": "^6.12.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.26",
    "apexcharts": "^3.16.0",
    "c3": "^0.4.24",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "d3": "^7.3.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "extend": "^3.0.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.2.1",
    "ng-chartist": "4.1.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^3.0.3",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-custom-validators": "8.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^7.3.12",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "13.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.0.1",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  }
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar tu `package.json` por favor? ¿Utilizas yarn o npm?

Comment: Buenas, utilizo NPM. Es un proyecto grande y tiene bastantes librerías el frontend. Te añado las dependencias del package.json a la pregunta

Comment: Revisa si esto te sirve: https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3262#issuecomment-529533978

Comment: He probado con muchas de las maneras que hay en los muchos issues abiertos en github pero no he conseguido dar con la tecla...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola he llegado a la solución.

Mi package json se ve así:

```
"d3-drag": "^3.0.0",
"d3-force": "^3.0.0",
"d3-selection": "^3.0.0",
"d3-transition": "^3.0.1",
"@types/d3-drag": "^3.0.1",
"@types/d3-force": "^3.0.3",
"@types/d3-selection": "^3.0.2",
"@types/d3-transition": "^3.0.1",
```

No utilizo directamente el módulo de d3 ya que parece que ahí estaba el error.

Para realizar los imports en el componente de Angular lo uso de esta forma:

```
import { select, selectAll } from 'd3-selection';
import { transition } from 'd3-transition';
import { forceSimulation, forceLink, forceManyBody, forceCenter } from 'd3-force';
import { drag } from 'd3-drag';
const d3 = { select, selectAll, transition, forceSimulation, forceLink, forceManyBody, forceCenter, drag };
```

Con esta configuración funciona correctamente.